# Changing font universally - richfaces

Tags: java, jsf, fonts, richfaces

i was wondering is there a way to change font universally for richfaces irrespective of what skin i am using.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a master css file for your project.

Just look at every rendered richfaces component. I believe that everyone has a common css class.

And, specify the font of this css class, in a master css file, for example:

```
.common-class-that-youve-looked {
    font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the RichFaces developers guide documentation for RF4.x ([Chapter 6. Skinning and theming](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Customizing_skins-Creating_a_new_skin)). Section [Skin parameter tables](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Skinning_overview-Skin_parameter_tables) states to use the parameter called `generalSizeFont`.

You install this via putting `aNameOfYourChoice.skin.properties` in you webapp's
`\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\skins` directory. Then add to your `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
  <param-value>aNameOfYourChoice</param-value>
</context-param>
```

My `aNameOfYourChoice.skin.properties` looks like this:

```
baseSkin=ruby
generalSizeFont=12px #your size of fonts
```